# SQL Select all if value exists in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three Table. The first Table contains a Rezipe with a id, the second Table contains the rezeptid with the ingredients and the third Table shows the ingredient with a restriction(vegan, meat...).

Im looking for a way to select a recipe if the ingredients dont contain a specific restriction and if it contains the restriction then return Null.

I first joined the three tables together and wrote the restriction in the where clausel, but i dont wanna return the recipe, if it contains a specific value

```
SELECT * 
FROM `rezepte` 
JOIN rezeptezutaten ON rezepte.REZEPTEID = rezeptezutaten.REZEPTEID 
JOIN inhaltsstoffe ON inhaltsstoffe.ZUTATENNR = rezeptezutaten.ZUTATENNR 
WHERE inhaltsstoffe.INHALTSSTOFFEID != 1;
```

Comment: Are you looking for CASE WHEN? It sounds like you need something like SELECT CASE WHEN inhaltsstoffe.INHALTSSTOFFEID = 1 THEN NULL ELSE yourValue END FROM...WHERE...

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output, and your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, please share how this problem is related to PHP (or remove the tag otherwise)

Comment: I am confused by the apparent contradiction between the 2 statements 'if it contains the restriction then return Null.' and 'but i dont wanna return the recipe, if it contains a specific value' adding sample data and expected outcome as text would help clarify.

Comment: This is a simple issue but better to explain with an example dataset, especially showing the raw data and the expected outcome. Don't what to return a row if contains value... Sounds like simple joins and where clause

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get all recipes that contain the ingredient with a particular restriction

```
select distinct rezeptezutaten.REZEPTEID 
from rezeptezutaten
JOIN inhaltsstoffe ON inhaltsstoffe.ZUTATENNR = rezeptezutaten.ZUTATENNR 
where  inhaltsstoffe.INHALTSSTOFFEID = 1
```

you can then use this as a subquery

```
select SELECT * 
FROM `rezepte` 
where REZEPTEID not in (
    select distinct rezeptezutaten.REZEPTEID 
    from rezeptezutaten
    JOIN inhaltsstoffe ON inhaltsstoffe.ZUTATENNR = rezeptezutaten.ZUTATENNR 
    where  inhaltsstoffe.INHALTSSTOFFEID = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

- not exactly sure but i believe you need a `case when`
- you can specify the conditions there multiples or single one's where you want to return the `null`
- you can then use this new column

```
SELECT 
*,
case when restriction in ('vegan','meat') then null else restriction end as new_value

FROM `rezepte` 
JOIN rezeptezutaten ON rezepte.REZEPTEID = rezeptezutaten.REZEPTEID 
JOIN inhaltsstoffe ON inhaltsstoffe.ZUTATENNR = rezeptezutaten.ZUTATENNR 
WHERE inhaltsstoffe.INHALTSSTOFFEID != 1
```

- if you are talking about excluding the row where you have any specific restriction then you can pass the filter directly on the `and` statement during the join
  something like

```
SELECT 
*,
case when restriction like '%vegan%' then null else restriction as new_value
FROM `rezepte` 
JOIN rezeptezutaten ON rezepte.REZEPTEID = rezeptezutaten.REZEPTEID 
JOIN inhaltsstoffe ON inhaltsstoffe.ZUTATENNR = rezeptezutaten.ZUTATENNR 
and restriction NOT in ('meat','vegan')
```